# Unable To Access Jar Published To Maven Central? - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-plugin, maven-central

I have an application, BankShots, that uses a jar that I created as a dependency, BankShotsContracts, which has been successfully published to Maven Central. I am unable to access BankShotsContracts from BankShots and continue to get failures when running `mvn compile` and `mvn install` on BankShots. I am however able to successfully run the same commands on BankShotsContracts.

Has anyone else run into this issue? If so, what am I doing wrong? (I'm very new to Maven)

I have provided the output of each command as well as the pom.xml for both applications and the settings.xml.

Here is the output when I run `mvn compile` on BankShotsContracts:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Inspecting build with total of 1 modules...
[INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
[INFO]   ... total of 1 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-staging-maven-plugin
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------< io.github.developerdomjones:BankShotsContracts >-----------
[INFO] Building io.github.developerdomjones:BankShotsContracts< 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ BankShotsContracts ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ BankShotsContracts ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.143 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-03T17:01:15-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the successful output when I run `mvn install` on BankShotsContracts which shows that my jar has successfully installed to the .m2/ folder:

```
[INFO] Installing /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShotsContracts/target/BankShotsContracts-0.0.1-sources.jar to /Users/dominiquejones/.m2/repository/io/github/developerdomjones/BankShotsContracts/0.0.1/BankShotsContracts-0.0.1-sources.jar
```

Here is the failure output when I run `mvn compile` on BankShots:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< com.bankshots:BankShots >-----------------------
[INFO] Building BankShots 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ BankShots ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShots/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ BankShots ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ BankShots ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 63 source files to /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShots/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShots/src/main/java/com/bankshots/feature/stock/StockServiceImpl.java:[16,37] package com.bankshotscontracts.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShots/src/main/java/com/bankshots/feature/stock/StockServiceImpl.java:[17,36] package com.bankshotscontracts.model does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShots/src/main/java/com/bankshots/feature/stock/StockService.java:[5,37] package com.bankshotscontracts.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShots/src/main/java/com/bankshots/feature/stock/StockService.java:[6,36] package com.bankshotscontracts.model does not exist
```

Here is the failure output when I run `mvn install` on BankShots:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.489 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-03T18:02:26-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project BankShots: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShots/src/main/java/com/bankshots/feature/stock/StockServiceImpl.java:[16,37] package com.bankshotscontracts.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShots/src/main/java/com/bankshots/feature/stock/StockServiceImpl.java:[17,36] package com.bankshotscontracts.model does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShots/src/main/java/com/bankshots/feature/stock/StockService.java:[5,37] package com.bankshotscontracts.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShots/src/main/java/com/bankshots/feature/stock/StockService.java:[6,36] package com.bankshotscontracts.model does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShots/src/main/java/com/bankshots/feature/stock/StockServiceImpl.java:[36,21] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Stock
[ERROR]   location: class com.bankshots.feature.stock.StockServiceImpl
[ERROR] /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShots/src/main/java/com/bankshots/feature/stock/StockService.java:[10,14] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Stock
[ERROR]   location: interface com.bankshots.feature.stock.StockService
[ERROR] /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShots/src/main/java/com/bankshots/feature/settings/AccountSettingsBusiness.java:[3,37] package com.bankshotscontracts.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShots/src/main/java/com/bankshots/feature/settings/AccountSettingsBusiness.java:[7,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Settings
[ERROR]   location: interface com.bankshots.feature.settings.AccountSettingsBusiness
[ERROR] /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShots/src/main/java/com/bankshots/feature/settings/AccountSettingsBusiness.java:[7,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Settings
[ERROR]   location: interface com.bankshots.feature.settings.AccountSettingsBusiness
[ERROR] /Users/dominiquejones/git/BankShots/src/main/java/com/bankshots/feature/settings/AccountSettingsBusiness.java:[15,51] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Settings
```

*pom.xml* for BankShots:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bankshots</groupId>
    <artifactId>BankShots</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>BankShots</name>
    <description>Description</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!--Spring Boot -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- BankShotsContracts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.developerdomjones</groupId>
            <artifactId>BankShotsContracts</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mockito -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Podam Factory -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.co.jemos.podam</groupId>
            <artifactId>podam</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Http Components -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
            <artifactId>sentry</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.decimal4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>decimal4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.github.developerdomjones</groupId>
                <artifactId>BankShotsContracts</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.bankshotscontracts.BankShotsContractsApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>bankshotscontracts</id>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

*pom.xml* for BankShotsContracts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.github.developerdomjones</groupId>
    <artifactId>BankShotsContracts</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}&lt;</name>
    <description>Contract jar for BankShots Application</description>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>MIT License</name>
            <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Dominique L. Jones</name>
            <email></email>
            <organization>DLJ</organization>
            <organizationUrl></organizationUrl>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/DeveloperDomJones/BankShotsContracts.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://github.com/DeveloperDomJones/BankShotsContracts.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/DeveloperDomJones/BankShotsContracts/tree/master</url>
    </scm>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Mongo DB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.8</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                    <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                    <autoReleaseAfterClose>false</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>bankshotscontracts</id>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

*settings.xml* from .m2/

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>ossrh</id>
      <username>DJones0521</username>
      <password>{jira password}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>ossrh</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <gpg.executable>gpg</gpg.executable>
        <gpg.passphrase>{pass-phrase}</gpg.passphrase>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using a SNAPSHOT version of Spring Boot: `2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` that's wrong.

Comment: I've changed the version to ```<version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>```, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Ok.. First step. Have you released the staging repository otherwise the sync to central will not done?

Comment: Yes, I am able to see my jar in Nexus Resository Manager and able to search for my jar in ```https://search.maven.org``` under ```io.github.developerdomjones```